# Android onClick from another class

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I have an class with a view and an avatar there which has a onClick property.

```
mSampleLayout = (BlurLayout)findViewById(R.id.blur_layout);
        View hover1 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_hover_sample, null);
        hover1.findViewById(R.id.avatar1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                Intent intent1 = new Intent (LoginActivity.this,AnaSoruActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
        mSampleLayout.setHoverView(hover1);
```

I would like to check if this avatar is clicked in another activity and do other stuff if it is clicked.

```
if(avatar1.isClicked???){
do something
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you have to use a listener or a EventBus. 
If your activity doesn't have reference to your class with the view then maybe your best solution is use a EventBus such as Otto: http://square.github.io/otto/

Post a event in your onClick listener and then subscribe your other activity to that events.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding a global variable in my onClick listener and incrementing value. Thanks for help tough